# dataTables loads slow with requireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs, datatables

When I use requireJS to load dataTables I see the unprocessed html for a short moment. Maybe because it waits for the DOM to be loaded ?

How can I load dataTables faster with requireJS ?

This is the main file

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'jquery': 'libs/jQuery-2-0-3',
    'datatables-plugin': 'plugins/jquery-datatables'
}
});

require(['jquery','datatables-plugin'], 
function($) {
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tablesorter-js').dataTable();

});
});
```

And the html in the head tag.

```
  <script data-main="/script/main" src="/script/require.js"></script>
```

As an example I call the scripts in the head tag without requireJS the datatable is executed right away.

```
 <script src="/script/libs/jQuery-2-0-3.js"></script>
   <script src="/script/plugins/jquery-datatables.js"></script>
```

and end of body tag

```
<script>
  $('.tablesorter-js').dataTable();
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is not a XY-thing? What version of requireJS? See this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/uqy6z/ datatables and requireJS  2.1.9

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing

```
require(['jquery','datatables-plugin'],
```

to

```
define(['jquery','datatables-plugin'],
```

Removed the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

And positioned the

```
<script data-main="/script/main" src="/script/require.js"></script>
```

At the end of the body tag.